# arrow tip when using ".. controls .." in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, commutative-diagrams

When I draw a commutative diagram with tikz, I normally use the syntax

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (0,0) {$A$};
\node (b) at (2,0) {$B$};
\node (c) at (4,0) {$C$};
\path[->]
(a) edge (b)
(b) edge (c)
(a) edge [bend left] (c)
(a) edge [bend right] (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This time, due to the size of the nodes, I need to use `.. controls (2,2) ..` to make the arrows avoid the nodes. But when I type

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (0,0) {$A$};
\node (b) at (2,0) {$B$};
\node (c) at (4,0) {$C$};
\draw[->]
(a) edge (b)
(b) edge (c)
(a) .. controls (2,2) ..  (c)
(a) .. controls (2,-2) .. (c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

the arrow tip appears only at the last line drawn using the `controls` syntax (and at the two edges). How can I specify that I want an arrow tip at every line?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to do with `tikz-cd`?

Comment: @Bernard: I'm used to using the `tikzpicture` environment. Usually, my diagrams are much larger and more complex.

Comment: You can use `edge[bend left=45]`

Comment: @percusse: In the posted example, I could do that. But it was just for showing which syntax I am using. In my diagram where I am actually going to apply this, I can only use `.. controls ..`to prevent the edges from crossing the nodes which are very long expressions.

Comment: You can do `\draw[->] .. ;` for each line rather than `\draw[->] .. .. .. ..;` for all lines.

Comment: Yes, I could just do it  this way :-) But I wondered whether there is maybe an more natural solution to this. It seems like such a natural thing that I'd be surprised if there was not a more direct solution. @Manuel

Comment: The thing is that in *most* cases, you only want the arrow tip at the end of the whole path - you don't want one at the end of every subpath. So PGF/TikZ goes with the usually-what-you-want. The best way to do this is to use distinct paths. You could use e.g. markings or decorations probably, but that's very clunky.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `arrows.meta` library and `looseness` key to control the distance from the control point to the two end points as said in the `pgfmanual`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage[tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a) at (0,0) {$A$};
\node (b) at (2,0) {$B$};
\node (c) at (4,0) {$C$};

\path[->]
(a) edge (b)
(b) edge (c)
(a) edge [out=80,in=100,looseness=5] (c)
(a) edge [out=-55,in=-125,looseness=1.5] (c);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That almost worked, but the shape of the edge does just not fit my diagram. I need the edge to move very far upward, then make a very sharp curve to the right, and then go on for a rather short distance. With the looseness alone, I cannot achieve this.

Comment: @StefanHamcke You can, adding one intermediate point (or may be more for more control).

Comment: @StefanHamcke Or you can try to change the `in` and `out` angles. It will change the shape of the edge.